# Getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT when seeding production database. (Too many requests?)

Tags: google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am using gmaps4rails gem to mark locations on a map.

When I seed my heroku app's database, I get

`#<Gmaps4rails::GeocodeStatus: The address you passed seems invalid, status was: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`.

for a number of the records that should be included in the database.

Thus, a good number of records end up being excluded. I'm pretty sure the reason is that there are too many requests being sent at one time.

One time, I got really lucky and there won't be any of these. However, most of the time there are quite a few. End up getting a map with around half of the locations I want marked on the map.

Any idea how I can perhaps put in some type of delay after seeding a certain number of records to prevent too many requests from being sent at one time?

Comment: You have a daily limit using google api. 1000 If I recall well